# Keycloak set required actions for user

Tags: authentication, keycloak, change-password

How to set required actions for user through keycloak API? I haven't found it in their admin rest API documentation. There is only

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email
```

but it works through email which does not fit my requirements. I would like to force user to change their password on next login.

Answer (score 1):

So, next api solves my issue

```
Update the user
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}
```

Comment: Hi, are you able to elaborate a bit more? A sample of the body request would be useful here

Comment: You can find it on their offical documentation:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/#_userrepresentation

you simply list all required actions in 'requiredActions' field of UserRepresentation

Comment: yes, you can. But is also good to have a answer on SO that is complete by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak 23.0.5 has 0 documentation and it is useless. Here is the answer I have found and worked for this version:
request PUT {url}/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}
request body:
{"requiredActions":

["UPDATE_PASSWORD","CONFIGURE_TOTP","VERIFY_EMAIL"]

}
This is the list of all actions you can use:
enum RequiredAction {
VERIFY_EMAIL, UPDATE_PROFILE, CONFIGURE_TOTP, UPDATE_PASSWORD, TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS
}

Hope this will help someone and save some time.